# Egorov's theorem application

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory

**Problem**

Let $\{f_k\}_{k \in \mathbb N}$ be a sequence of measurable functions defined on $E \subset \mathbb R^n$ with $E$ measurable and $|E|<\infty$, such that $f_k \to 0$ a.e.. Show that there exists a subsequence $\{f_{k_j}\}_{j \in \mathbb N}$ such that $\sum_{j \in \mathbb N} |f_{k_j}|<\infty$ a.e.

I thought of using Egorov's theorem, so for each $\epsilon_n=\dfrac{1}{n}$, there exists a closed subset $F_n \subset E$ with $|E \setminus F_n|<\epsilon_n$ and such that $f_n \rightrightarrows 0$ on $F_n$. For each $j$, I can pick $n_j$ with $|f_{n_j}|<\dfrac{1}{2^j}$ in $F_j$ and I can also pick $n_1<n_2<...<n_j<...$

It is easy to see that complement of the set $F=\bigcup_{j \in \mathbb N} F_j$ has measure zero. The problem is that I cannot affirm $|f_{n_j}|<\dfrac{1}{2^j}$ in all $F$ but just in $F_{n_j}$. I can assure this on the intersection $\bigcap_{j \in \mathbb N} F_j$ but the complement of this set is not of measure zero, so the series is not convergent almost everywhere.

Any hints to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct $F_n$ as you did, but then let $F_n' = F_1 \cup \dots \cup F_n$.  Then we again have $|E \setminus F_n'| < \epsilon_n$ and $f_n \rightrightarrows 0$ on $F_n'$.  Moreover, $F_1' \subset F_2' \subset \dots$ which will be useful later.  Choose the $n_j$s such that $|f_{n_j}| < 2^{-j}$ on $F_{j}'$ instead.
Now let's set $F = \bigcup_n F_n'$ instead.

Hint 2: If you do that, then for any fixed $x \in F$, you cannot guarantee $|f_{n_j}(x)| < \frac{1}{2^j}$ for *every* $j$, but you can guarantee it for *all but finitely many* $j$...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have some doubts: suppose I could construct these nested sets, for each $j$, I pick $n_j$ with $|f_{n_j}| \leq \dfrac{1}{2^j}$ and I can pick $n_1<...<n_k<...$.

Comment: Since you've mentioned  "all but finitely many $j$", I suppose that your suggestion is to consider the set $F=\bigcup_{k \in \mathbb N} \bigcap_{n\geq k} F_n$. Then, for each $x \in F$, there is $k$ such that $|f_{n_j}(x)|<\dfrac{1}{2^j}$ for all $j \geq k$., so we would have $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|f_{n_j}(x)|=\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}|f_{n_j}(x)|+\sum_{j=k}^{\infty}|f_{n_j}(x)|<\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}|f_{n_j}(x)|+\sum_{j=k}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2^j}< \infty$. I don't see how can I choose the closed sets $F_n$ such that they form an increasing sequence, could you help me with that?

Comment: That's not what I meant - if you define $F$ that way, you can no longer guarantee that $F^c$ has measure 0.  Rather, see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Convergence a.e. on a finite measure space implies convergence in measure. So we may choose $k_1$ such that $k\geqslant k_1$ implies $\mu\left(\left\{x:|f_k(x)|> 2^{-k}\mu(E)^{-1}\right\}\right)<2^{-k}\mu(E)^{-1}$, and inductively $k_j\geqslant k_{j-1}$ such that $k\geqslant k_j$ implies $\mu\left(\left\{x:|f_k(x)|>2^{-k_j}\mu(E)^{-1}\right\}\right)<2^{-k_j}\mu(E)^{-1}$ and $k_j\stackrel{j\to\infty}\longrightarrow\infty$. We may assume WLOG that $2^{-k_1}\mu(E)^{-1}<1$. Hence
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^\infty |f_{k_j}| &\leqslant \sum_{j=1}^\infty 2^{-k_j}\mu(E)^{-1}\mu(E)+2^{-k_j}\mu(E)^{-1}\\
&\leqslant \mu(E)^{-1}\sum_{j=1}^\infty 2^{-k_j}\\
&\leqslant \mu(E)^{-1}\\
&<\infty.
\end{align}

Comment: P.S. I'm really tired so if my proof is flawed feel free to point it out and I will correct it later.

Comment: Unless there are some a.e.'s missing, you seem to have "proved" that $\sum_j |f_{k_j}| < \infty$ everywhere, which cannot be generally true (suppose there is some fixed null set where every $f_k$ equals 1).